# Trouble running Hallon (libspotify) examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, spotify

I'm trying to run the examples provided by the Hallon gem https://github.com/Burgestrand/Hallon

I followed all these instructions:
https://github.com/Burgestrand/Hallon/wiki

But, I'm still having an issue. Below is the error I'm getting. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

> Basils-MacBook-Pro:Hallon Basil$ ruby examples/show_published_playlists_of_user.rb
>   /Users/Basil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- weak_observable (LoadError)
>       from /Users/Basil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
>       from /Users/Basil/Desktop/Hallon/lib/hallon.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /Users/Basil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
>       from /Users/Basil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
>       from /Users/Basil/Desktop/Hallon/examples/example_support.rb:46:in`'
>       from examples/show_published_playlists_of_user.rb:4:in `require_relative'
>       from examples/show_published_playlists_of_user.rb:4:in`'

Comment: `gem install weak_observable`

Comment: Post your answer in a separate question so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message contains the answer:

```
require': cannot load such file -- weak_observable (LoadError)
```

Which means this should solve your problem:

```
gem install weak_observable
```